# Inconsistent behaviour of shared variable

Tags: parallelization

It is well known that assignments to a variable shared between the main kernel and the subkernels are only executed by the main kernel. I suppose that when a subkernel has to assign to a shared variable, it sends the command to the main kernel for execution. Therefore, I was surprised to see a situation where the subkernel simply refused to do the assignment. Here is a highly simplified example.

```
demo[] := Module[{asc},
  Quiet[CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[2]];
  SetSharedVariable[asc];
  Print[Attributes[asc]];
  ParallelEvaluate[Print[Attributes[asc]]];
  asc=Association[{}];
  ParallelDo[AssociateTo[asc,$KernelID->0], {i,1,$KernelCount}];
  Print[asc];
  ParallelEvaluate[asc[$KernelID]++];
  Print[asc];
  ParallelEvaluate[AssociateTo[asc, $KernelID->1+asc[$KernelID]]];
  Print[asc];
]

In[6]:= demo[]
During evaluation of In[6]:= {Temporary}
(kernel 1) {Protected}
(kernel 2) {Protected}
During evaluation of In[6]:= <|2->0,1->0|>
(kernel 1) Set::wrsym :  Symbol asc$3017 is Protected.
(kernel 2) Set::wrsym :  Symbol asc$3017 is Protected.
During evaluation of In[6]:= <|2->0,1->0|>
During evaluation of In[6]:= <|2->1,1->1|>
```

I open two subkernels and construct a shared variable `asc`. The output shows that in the main kernel it has attribute `Temporary`, being a `Module` variable, but on the subkernels it has attribute `Protected`. Then I assign an association to `asc`, with keys the `KernelID`'s and initial value 0 for each key. No problem.

Then on each subkernel I use the increment function for increasing the value of the `KernelID`. Both subkernels report that they cannot do that because of the variable is protected. But when on each subkernel I increase the value by using `AssociateTo`, it works.

Is there a simple explanation why we cannot use the increment function on the subkernels, or has it to be considered as a minor bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Try reaching out to Wolfram support, see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do parallel computing, it's better to use immutable data but not mutable data.

In:

```
demo[] := Module[{asc, xs}, Quiet[CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[2]];
  SetSharedVariable[asc];
  Print[Attributes[asc]];
  ParallelEvaluate[Print[Attributes[asc]]];
  asc = Association[{}];

  xs = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> 0, {i, 1, $KernelCount}];
  AssociateTo[asc, xs];
  Print[asc];

  xs = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> asc[$KernelID] + 1, {i, 
     1, $KernelCount}];
  AssociateTo[asc, xs];
  Print[asc];

  xs = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> asc[$KernelID] + 1, {i, 
     1, $KernelCount}];
  AssociateTo[asc, xs];
  Print[asc];]
demo[]
```

Out:

```
{Temporary}
{Protected}
{Protected}
<|14->0,13->0|>
<|14->1,13->1|>
<|14->2,13->2|>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not so familiar with mutable and immutable data, but I think I understand what you mean. However, that does not really answer my question. I am puzzled by the fact that in one situation the subkernels refuse to do an assignment to a shared variable and in another one they do assign. Have you any ideas about that?

Comment: asc has the attribute protected when you do ParallelEvaluate. You can't change it during parallel evaluation.